# How to specify authenticity of SSL for querying APIs?

Tags: import, json-format, query, api

While ago I was using this command with no issue, now I have an SSL error:

```
Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=\
pageimages&pithumbsize=400&pilimit=max&list=search&srsearch=" <> 
  ToString[query] <> "&utf8=&format=json", "JSON"]
```

[image]

How could I solve it ?

I tried the followings:

1. open the url with the browser, find the certificate, then locating that certificate in my system (using keychain in mac) and store a copy in the folder of the file, but format is not recognised:

   `myCert = Import["/Users/this/Sites/that/R&D/certificates/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.crt"];`

[image]

and neither from the digicert url:

```
Import["http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2HighAssuranceServerCA.\
crt", {"PEM", "CRT"}]
```

[image]

2. Tried with curl:

   Import["!curl -X GET-H 'Content-type: application/json' -H 'Accept:
   application/json'" <>
   "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageimages&
   pithumbsize=400&pilimit=max&list=search&srsearch=" <>
   ToString["DNA"] <> "&utf8=&format=json", "JSON"]

[image]

I wanna simply query APIs and import json data in the most simple way.

How can I solve it?

Comment: You have not defined `query`. I see no error on Windows 10 Mathematica 12.2 if I use `query="DNA"`.

Comment: mmm but I do see it with my laptop. Mac, Mathematica 11.3.0